# Where to find data-icon unicode values

Tags: css, unicode, icons

i'm trying to use İcomoon font for css icons. I downloaded and configured in css file. But i don't know icon's unicode values. How can i see all icons' unicode values to write as a value of data-icon attribute.

Comment: Don't you map icomoon images directly to unicode values? I thought that was the point.

Comment: When you use the icomoon app (http://icomoon.io/app/#/select) to select your icons and build your font, you are given an index.html file in the downloaded zip file - this shows you the icon along with the unicode value.

Comment: @David Randall, You should add this as the answer for the OP to accept. Cos this accurately addresses the question and worked for me too.

Answer (score 9):

1. Go to https://icomoon.io/app/#/select.
2. Select the icon(s) that you need.
3. Click on Generate Font.
4. Hover on the icon and click on Get Code.
5. Copy the HTML/CSS which contains the unicode of the icon.