# How to change the Google Nexus website menu

Tags: html, web, icons

https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/30/google-nexus-website-menu/

I am trying to use the google-nexus-website-menu options provided on the above link for the website that I am designing for my project.

For that I need to change the menu options and also the menu icons.

I am able to make other changes such as changing the size of the menu, submenu, font, width and all that. But not sure as how do I change the icons provided or how do I add any new icons in that place.

I am new to this area. so any sort of help is appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: Hey @Harvey, I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37886790/923275) might help you. You'll probably have to go to [icomoon.io](https://icomoon.io) to generate your own font with the icons that you need.